# Shaliach Tzibbur missed out one or more blessings in the repetition of the amidah. What to do later?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, chazzan-prayer-leader

What should one do if the Shaliach Tzibbur missed out one or more blessings in the repetition of the amidah and it was only pointed out to him after he had finished?

Does he have to repeat the amidah correctly, or do we say that, since nowadays he doesn't acquit anyone of their obligation to pray, he does not have to repeat?

Comment: Tangentially related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30988

Comment: Followup question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34311

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch (OC 126:3) rules that for any mistake that would require an individual to repeat Shemonei Esrieh, if the Chazzan made such a mistake in his repetition he would have to say it over again. (There are some exceptions, but they are not relevant to our question.) The Sefer Shegiyos Mi Yavin (a book dealing with the laws of mistakes that occur during davening and brochos, 15:14) brings as an example of this if he skipped out one of the brochos. (In such a case, he writes that they would say kedusha again, and the congregation would say modim derabanan, and he brings several opinions regarding birkas kohanim).

Comment: Though Yaaleh Veyavo at Shacharit may be an exception to this.

Comment: @DoubleAA Right, Shulchan Aruch there does point out some exceptions due to Tirchah Detzibura, but I didn't mention this in my answer as skipping one of the brochos is not one of them.