# Is it right to point out that the Chazzan omitted a brocho in his repetition of the amida?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, chazzan-prayer-leader

In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34213/shaliach-tzibbur-missed-out-one-or-more-blessings-in-the-repetition-of-the-amida) we learnt that if the [Chazzan](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1879) left out a brocho  in his repetition of the amida he would have to repeat the repetition.

Is it right to point out that the Chazzan omitted a brocho?

If he is told, he is very likely to be embarrassed and [embarrassing someone is a Torah prohibition, {page 20 column 2}](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%205%20Letters.pdf) whereas the [fixed form of our prayers is rabbinic](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/862345/jewish/What-Is-Jewish-Prayer.htm) .

So I might think that it is best not to notice the omission.

Comment: We correct Baalei Keriya when they make mistakes which are problematic.

Comment: The linked question states that the halachah mandates that he repeat the amida. Everyone makes mistakes in life. So as long as the mistake is pointed out in a respectful manner then I don't know why that would be what the Torah considers embarrassment.

Comment: @eramm The question was based on an actual occurrence. I judged by the redness of his face at the time he was told!

Comment: Since the halacha mandates it as long as it's done in a sensitive manner (key word = sensitive) then it needs to be done regardless if the origin is rabbinic. it's halacha now. see this discussion http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/207549/to-correct-or-not-to-correct-the-baal-koreh.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 126:1 - "mazkirim oso" ("we remind him").  In fact, if the [shatz](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1879) skips over Birchas HaMalshinim, the [Michaber](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1693) goes as far to say "misalkin oso" ("we remove him") due to concerns of apikorsus.  The Mishneh Brurah expands that concern to other brochas.

Additionally, a shatz can be replaced with another shatz if he is unable to restart from the point at which he messed up (126:2).

It would seem that kavod hatzibbur and communal needs outweigh individual embarrassment in this case.

Comment: Note that When Shulchan Aruch stated _"mazkirim osi"_ it was referring to mid-repetition, whereas this question is about if the mistake was noticed _after_ the repetition had already been completed.. (I am not disagreeing with the conclusion; just pointing out that it's not the exact case).