# Using a different text of Birkat Minim

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, nuschaot, heresy

It is known that we [remove a sha"tz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30988/why-is-a-prayer-leader-still-removed-for-omitting-vlamalshinim) for omitting Birkat Minim. However, there are multiple texts that I know of, including: Vilmalshinim, Laminim, and Vilam'shumadim. There are also small variants in wording within these major forms (t'oveid, yoveidu, et c.).

Considering this, would/should a sha"tz be removed for using a different nusach for the beracha?

Comment: A careful reading of the linked question essentially answers this one. The Magen Avraham and Mishna B'rura cited there extend the ruling of earlier authorities to say that if someone ended the blessing properly but skipped the beginning part entirely, they are not removed as *sha"tz*, and certainly if they used a different variant. There is some discussion (discussed in the edit to the other question) among the *poskim* regarding whether a *sha"tz* must be removed for using the popular text of *V'lamalshinim* used by most Ashkenazim nowadays, since it omits mention of heretics.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the Talmud instructed the removal of the *shat"z* is because his omission  was suggestive of ideological sympathies with the heretics of the time/*meshumadim*. That would not seem to be at all relevant to someone having a different *nusach* unless there was significant reason to suspect that indeed a similar ideological issue on the part of the *shat"z* was the real reason for his deviation from the *nusach*. (Nonetheless, I believe the normative *halacha* is that the *chazan* is expected to follow the *nusach* of the community.)

Comment: How do you know this rule falls away when the reason does too? That's not how Jews treat most rules.

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed if he refused to say the bracha at all you'd probably be right (and presumably if he composed his own, new nusach). But the OP was asking where he said a traditional nusach, just not the same one as the congregation. That seems unrelated to both the reasoning behind, and the gezeira itself.

Comment: lowiean: perhaps.

Comment: @DoubleAA (Also, the *baalei tosfot* do indeed suggest a rule of *batel hataam batel hagezera* in cases where the minhag has already shifted, e.g. *mayim achronim*, *mayim megulim*, *rikud* on *shabbos* and *yom tov*, etc.)

Comment: Has the minhag here shifted?

Comment: @DoubleAA Inasmuch as there are now different nuschaos...

Comment: @DoubleAA (although it's not so easy to say batel hataam...)

Comment: loewian, the asker doesn't say "traditional" (as you attribute to him in your comment). Suppose a liberal Jewish group omits a phrase from this _b'racha_ because it "unfairly targets minority populations". Would your answer apply to that _nusach_?

Comment: @msh210 that was my understanding of his question but I agree with your point and that's what I meant when I said it's not easy to say batel hataam since that would presumably qualify. Though I suppose one could suggest that according to the Chazon Ish that argues with the Rambam and holds we only have tinok shenishba nowadays there is more to discuss...