Why should one be immediately replaced if he messed up during the brocho of heretics?
B"H
The Rambam laws of Tefillah chapter 10 halacha 3 writes

ג שְׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר שֶׁטָּעָה וְנִבְהַל וְלֹא יָדַע מֵהֵיכָן יַתְחִיל
וְשָׁהָה שָׁעָה יַעֲמֹד אַחֵר תַּחְתָּיו. וְאִם טָעָה בְּבִרְכַּת
הָאֶפִּקוֹרְסִין אֵין מַמְתִּינִין לוֹ אֶלָּא מִיָּד יַעֲמֹד אַחֵר
תַּחְתָּיו שֶׁמָּא אֶפִּיקוֹרְסוּת נִזְרְקָה בּוֹ. וְהוּא שֶׁלֹּא
הִתְחִיל בָּהּ אֲבָל אִם הִתְחִיל בָּהּ מַמְתִּינִין לוֹ שָׁעָה. וְלֹא
יְהֵא הַשֵּׁנִי סַרְבָן בְּאוֹתָהּ שָׁעָה:

That if a shliach tzibbur makes a mistake in the blessing asking Hashem to remove the heretics from the world and cause them to be troubled, he is immediately replaced, "because maybe (a thought of) heresy was thrown into him".
It seems like there's some additional reasoning between the lines that I'm trying to grasp.
Is the reason because as a heretic he personally wouldn't want to ask Hashem to remove the heretics from the world, and therefore his stuttering is a sign to us that he was hesitant to say it, or is the reason because as he was saying the blessing, Hashem instantly (or potentially even before it was even started) began to answer his prayers (of causing the heretics to be troubled etc.) by causing him to inadvertently mess up?
Even though the simple reading of the halacha, as well as the explanation of shteinzelts which implies that he, the shliach tzibbur, is intentionally avoiding it:

מִינוּת נִזְרְקָה בּוֹ. שמא נעשה מין, ומשום כך הוא משתמט מן הברכה
לאיבוד המינים

Support the first way, the obvious problem with that is as follows.
If he's actually a min (or apikoros, according to the two versions of Rambam here), then according to hilchos Teshuva, he either doesn't believe that the Creator exists at all or he doesn't believe that the Creator supervises the actions of man, so then why would he be afraid of saying the blessing (the underlying implications being that he's afraid that if he says it, the power of prayer will cause Hashem to listen to it)?
And if one were to say that there were different kinds of minim/apikorsim that could have also believed a certain type of creator, but would a heretic consider himself a heretic?
Are there any commentators on the gemara, Rambam, Shulchan Aruch or other sources that discuss this question?

@TamirEvan thanks for that reference. Although even there it's still ambiguous as to the reason for why he was silent at the blessing, it doesn't specify if it was willingly or because Hashem would have answered the prayer or prevented it from being said by a heretic, שֶׁמָּא            מִינוּת נִזְרְקָה בּוֹ. שמא נעשה מין, ומשום כך הוא משתמט מן הברכה לאיבוד המינים

"משתמט" means 'causes himself to separate', and (at least in Modern [Israeli] Hebrew) expresses a person trying/wanting to get out of doing something. If the commentator wanted to say that an external force brought him to it, he would not have phrased it that way. (Maybe he'd use 'נשמט', which is more passive, instead.) That's my opinion.

@tamir I think you're right. See edit

Duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30988/

@fred that question is asking why the halacha still applies today, this one is asking the underlying reasoning behind it

"If he's actually a min (or apikoros, according to the two versions of Rambam here), then according to hilchos Teshuva, he either doesn't believe that the Creator exists at all or he doesn't believe that the Creator supervises the actions of man ..." Those aren't the only two options. A Min can be someone who believes there are more than one Creator, and may not want one of them answering this prayer upon him. An Apikoros can be one who only denies Moses' prophecy, but still believes that the Creator supervises enough the actions of man, to answer this prayer upon him.

Or, even though he doesn't believe the prayer will be answered, he still doesn't want to say something that promotes his destruction. Like how I wouldn't say (lehavdil) "Zeus, please kill all the Jews"

Review H. Teshubha 3:6-8 there are other types of minuth/apiqorsuth. Conceivably there are types that believe in the power of God and that they would accordingly be calling for their own demise and the demise of those with shared sympathies.

@B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem See this answer.

The first Christians believed in Hashem. When they first adopted the idea of a trinity, they thought it was the god of the Torah. In both cases, they wouldn’t want to pray for the destruction of Christianity and its political dominance.

@Qwertrl but would they consider themselves minim?

"... but would a heretic consider himself a heretic?" (1) Presumably he would know/suspect that such a blessing was intended against the likes of him...

... (2) If such a heretic didn't consider himself a heretic, he presumably wouldn't pause, or try to get out of saying the blessing, either. The point of the halakha is not catch and remove all heretics from being shliach tzibbur, but to limit the odds of a heretic continuing to lead the prayer, based on a heuristic. There still will be some false positives (that just happened to stop/skip at the wrong point), and others could slip through uncaught (confirmed heretics that sail through the prayer).

@B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem The original text(s), variations of which are seen in older manuscripts of Siddurim and the Talmud, included explicit references to Christianity, and/or to the Christian dominion.
